# I thought this is already tail recursive. But if not how do I make it so?

Tags: recursion, groovy, tail-recursion

Not the best title for the question, I agree. But I couldn't come up with something else. Sorry.

Writing a simple Singly Linked List code in Groovy, I want to add a method which takes in two lists and appends the right one to the left one. This is what I cam up with.

```
private static class Node {
    Node next = null
    def head

    @TailRecursive
    Node append(Node left = this, Node right) {
        if (!right) return left
        if (!left) return right

        if (!left.next) left.next = right
        else left.next = append(left.next, right)

        return left
    }
}
```

But I got the error,

```
LinkedList.groovy: 23: Recursive call could not be transformed by @TailRecursive. Maybe it's not a tail call.
 @ line 23, column 30.
               else head.next = append(head.next, tail)
```

Is it because of the return statement in the end that it's not tail recursive? How do I fix this?

Comment: A tail-recursive function must *return the value of the recursive case immediately* - you can't use it in any way otherwise.

Comment: Okay, I get it now. However how do I make this function tail recursive. I know it can be done, since I read about it in a book on Scala. However, how do I do it in Groovy?

Comment: Consider the function defined as `append(prev_tail, tail, tail_right)` (this can be a helper function)

Comment: So did you try that definition yet? It would be called recursively as `append(left, left.next, right)` so the work can be "pushed down". Alternatively, and cleaner (but it entirely tosses out the current code), just create a `lastnode` function to iterate the the left tail to end. Then modify the last node and move on.

Comment: @user2864740 Sorry I got a bit busy and could not get back to the question. Thanks for your suggestion. It worked. However I did not understand the second approach. Could you describe it a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the tip [user2864740](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2864740/user2864740) gave, here's the tail recursive implementation. It should be as efficient as the non-tail-recursive one I posted in the question.

```
@TailRecursive
Node append(Node prevTail = this, Node tail = this?.next, Node right) {
    if (!right) return left
    if (!prevTail) return right

    if (!tail) prevTail.next = right
    else return append(tail, tail?.next, right)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like below would suffice?

```
import groovy.transform.TailRecursive

@TailRecursive
LinkedList mergeLinkedList(LinkedList left = [], LinkedList right = []) {
    if ( !left ) {
        right
    } else if ( !right ) {
        left
    } else {
        left.add( right.head() )
        mergeLinkedList( left, right.tail() ) 
    }
}

def left = (1..100) as LinkedList, right = (200..500) as LinkedList

assert mergeLinkedList( left, right ) == ((1..100) + (200..500)) as LinkedList
```

Comment: What if I don't want to write it for the inbuilt `LinkedList` class but for the class I have in the question? Adding an element to the end of `left` in every recursive call will process `n`, `n + 1` ... `n + m` in the end (assuming `left` has `n` elements and right has `m`). This should result in `O(n + m^2)` complexity as far as I can see. My implementation, though not tail recursive, would take only `O(n)` if I am not wrong. Is there a way we can achieve the same complexity using tail recursion?